# Change xubuntu settings from terminal

Tags: scripts, settings, dconf, gsettings

I'd like to port [my dconf settings](https://github.com/arturojosejr/post-install-script/blob/master/install/mate-settings) to xubuntu, but I don't know how. Give me an example with this one:

```
dconf write /org/mate/terminal/profiles/profile0/background-color "'#28272C2B3433'"
```

I want to make all fonts bigger too.

Comment: Does `dconf write /org/mate/terminal/profiles/profile0/background-color 28272C2B3433` not work?

Comment: It looks like Xubuntu uses `xfconf-query` instead of `dconf`, I never used it myself so far, https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=10836 should be useful as it shows some examples how to use the command.

Comment: Thanks I've already found how to change the repeat speed. `xfconf-query -c keyboards -p /Default/KeyRepeat/Delay -s 150`. The terminal ones are tricky because they don't use profile0 for a new profile but something like 8fe552cf-7916-4e31-84fe-f7fa6d9bed59 instead. So I have to make a variable that gets the profile name first. With dconf it would be `dconf dump / | grep /legacy/profiles:/ | sed -r 's/^\[|\]$//g' | head -n1`. I don't know how will it be with xfconf.